# FIFA 16 Sprinting + Teammate Run issue in PC

Tags: pc, fifa-16

In Fifa 15, I could press Sprint + Player Run/modifier to run along the wings and tell teammate to run so I could make a good pass forward.

In Fifa 16, when I try to do the same thing, the player stops sprinting for as long as I press the player run button. It's so weird and it's annoying me a lot.

Can someone provide some advice on this? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In order to tell a teammate to run, use the left shift key. Since Fifa 16 for PC has some different controls, here are some more controls:

(I found these controls on this website: http://segmentnext.com/2015/09/23/fifa-16-pc-custom-controls-guide-how-to-customize-controls/)

**Attacking Buttons**

Through Ball – A

Lob Pass/Cross/Header – S

Shoot/Volley/Header – Left-click

Short Pass/Header – Right-click

Player Movement – Mouse

Pace Control – Mouse

Sprint – Mouse

Teammate Run – R + Mouse

** Player Run/Modifier – Left Shift **

Finesse Shot/Modifier – D

Tactics – Up arrow

Mentality – Left arrow/Right arrow

Custom Tactics – Down arrow

Skill Moves – Scroll wheel

Pause – Esc

Help – F

**Defending Buttons**

Jockey – Mouse

Sprint – Mouse

Change Player – Left Shift

Mark Man – R + Mouse

Tackle (Push or Pull) – Left-Click

Contain – Right-Click

Teammate Contain – D

Sliding Tackle – S

Rush Goalkeeper – A (Hold)

Tactics – Up Arrow

Mentality – Left Arrow/Right Arrow

Custom Tactics – Down Arrow

Pause – Esc

Help/Control the Goalkeeper – F

Comment: I dont think you understand the problem. You can change the keys man, I use space bar for player run modifier and it works fine as long as i am not sprinting.

Comment: @anakin316 I did not know this because it was not in the description. You should add it in your question.